# MySQL Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' while create connection in Java

Tags: java, mysql

There are user 'pawa' on my Ubuntu. When I try create Connection object with code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("user", "root");
properties.put("password", "password");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library_db@localhost");
```

I get error like:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'pawa'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I dont understand why my user appear here? In properties I put root user. I give all permission to my user with

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON library_db.* TO 'pawa'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

but it doesnt work.

---

*Edit to include screenshots supplied in comments:*

[image: Primary User Account]

[image: Root User Account]

Comment: Umm ... applications cannot connect to MySQL as `root`. It's simply not allowed unless you have intentionally broken MySQL's security policies. Java is probably trying to accommodate this rule and replacing the username. If the Java application need admin access to MySQL, be sure to create a new user and grant them all privileges. This is the correct way to give an application administrator rights to MySQL.

Comment: @matigo I alredy create pawa user in mysql and grant it all privilages

https://postimg.cc/LqRT8V9C
https://postimg.cc/w3PQmzxs

Comment: Is MySQL running on the same machine as the Java application? Are any of these aspects running in a virtual machine or Docker container? Aside from a bad password, one possible cause for this would be that the Java application is not on `localhost` but identifying as coming from somewhere else 

Comment: Running on same machine. No virtual machine. Password for root and pawa are the same (but pawa in mysql have different password with pawa as my ubuntu user)
How can I detect how Java is identifying ?

Comment: If you created and granted access to 'pawa', why don't you just use it instead of root?

Comment: It does not change anything if I write properties.put("user", "root");
And I use Workbench when working with mysql. There are already created connection to which I want connect by Java. User root is used in this connection.
https://postimg.cc/njPGnhvV/661fd6b3
https://postimg.cc/WhrwPjtj/ca203946